# safeControl and versioning in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint project (web parts, user controls ...) and I have created Safe Control for it in the Web.config file.

If I change the version of the assemlby (1.0.0.0) do I need to modify web.config file of the web Application?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The general recommendation is that you never update the AssemblyVersion of WebPart assemblies, because you have to update:

- The SafeControl entries in web.config (for letting it run)
- The .webpart files (for getting new instances)
- Assembly redirect entries in web.config (for already inserted instances)

For more reference see:

- [Web Part Versioning with assembly redirection](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Versioning-with-assembly-redirection.aspx)
- [SharePoint WebPart Versioning](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-webpart-versioning/)

Comment: thanks, If I have a project for all my WebParts and let it be (never update this assembly). Do I need to update SafeControl for other assemblies which do not contain any WebPart (modules, features ...) if I change Version?

Comment: The rule applies to anything which needs a SafeControl entry: WebParts, SitePage baseclass and web controls, Custom Workflow Action,... So in general SharePoint developers usually don't update AssemblyVersion. But of cause you should always update the version of your feature